# Scroll Position Lost on JQuery hide and fadeIn

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

Have a list of questions on page, which can be very long.  I have created a small list here in the sample code.  User scrolls to question, clicks on it, and the list hides, the single questions appears.  User reads and clicks the "X" to close it, and the original list re-appears in the SAME POSITION (what I want, but don't get).

Problem is that the list reappears at the top instead of maintaining its scroll position.

Changing to show/hide, fadeIN/fadeOut, using event.preventDefault(), doesn't seem to make a difference.

Code uses Bootstrap 4/Jquery.
(Zoom in on the browser to get the scrollbars for testing)

Code below:

```js
    //********************************************************************************************************
    //     Clone Question, display on its own, hide existing list of questions
    //********************************************************************************************************     
    $(document).on('click', '[data-name="question"]', function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        var qid = $(this).attr("data-qid");//id of the question being answered        
        //var clone = $(this).clone();//clone entire question element to paste into new space
        var clone = $('#header'+qid).clone();//clone entire question element to paste into new space    
        $('#load_data').hide();
        $(clone).hide().appendTo('#load_single_answer').fadeIn(1000);
        var html = '<div class="container">'+//provide an X button to close the single question display
            '<div class="exit btn btn-light btn-space col-12 box displ text-center align-self-center" style="font-size:120%"><strong>X</strong></div>'+
            '</div>';                    
        $(html).appendTo('#load_single_answer'); 
    });
    //**********************************************************************
    //    Close single question display, bring back the list of questions
    //**********************************************************************
    $(document).on('click', '.exit', function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        //restore all background data
        $('#load_data').fadeIn(500);
        $('#load_single_answer').empty();//clear out single answer data
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- JQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>   
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body style="background-color:#f2f2f2;">

    <!-- loading point for displaying single questions and answers -->
    <div class='container' style="max-width:900px;">
        <div id="load_single_answer"></div>
    </div>
 
    <div id="main">
            <!-- Question and Answers loaded here via ajax call -->
            <div id = "dataX" class="container p-0" style="max-width: 900px;">
                <div id="load_data">               
                    <!-- BEGINNING LIST OF QUESTIONS-->
                    <!-- questions here -->
                    <div data-name="results">
                        <!-- individual question container with DETAILS link  -->
                        <div class="card-header" id="header165" style="border-radius:10px;background-color:white;border:none;">                 
                            <div data-qid="165" data-aid="0" data-name="question" style="cursor: pointer;">
                                <div style="margin-bottom:-7px;">
                                    <h5 style="font-family: &quot;Verdana&quot;, Verdana;font-weight: bolder;margin-top:0px;"><span style="white-space:pre-wrap;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam?</span>
                                </div>                   
                            </div> 
                        </div> 
                        <br>
                    </div>                    
                    <!-- questions here -->
                    <div data-name="results">
                        <!-- individual question container with DETAILS link  -->
                        <div class="card-header" id="header166" style="border-radius:10px;background-color:white;border:none;">                 
                            <div data-qid="166" data-aid="0" data-name="question" style="cursor: pointer;">
                                <div style="margin-bottom:-7px;">
                                    <h5 style="font-family: &quot;Verdana&quot;, Verdana;font-weight: bolder;margin-top:0px;"><span style="white-space:pre-wrap;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam?</span>
                                </div>                   
                            </div> 
                        </div> 
                        <br>
                    </div>
                    <!-- questions here -->
                    <div data-name="results">
                        <!-- individual question container with DETAILS link  -->
                        <div class="card-header" id="header167" style="border-radius:10px;background-color:white;border:none;">                 
                            <div data-qid="167" data-aid="0" data-name="question" style="cursor: pointer;">
                                <div style="margin-bottom:-7px;">
                                    <h5 style="font-family: &quot;Verdana&quot;, Verdana;font-weight: bolder;margin-top:0px;"><span style="white-space:pre-wrap;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam?</span>
                                </div>                   
                            </div> 
                        </div> 
                        <br>
                    </div>
                    <!-- questions here -->
                    <div data-name="results">
                        <!-- individual question container with DETAILS link  -->
                        <div class="card-header" id="header168" style="border-radius:10px;background-color:white;border:none;">                 
                            <div data-qid="168" data-aid="0" data-name="question" style="cursor: pointer;">
                                <div style="margin-bottom:-7px;">
                                    <h5 style="font-family: &quot;Verdana&quot;, Verdana;font-weight: bolder;margin-top:0px;"><span style="white-space:pre-wrap;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam?</span>
                                </div>                   
                            </div> 
                        </div> 
                        <br>
                    </div>
                    <!-- questions here -->
                    <div data-name="results">
                        <!-- individual question container with DETAILS link  -->
                        <div class="card-header" id="header169" style="border-radius:10px;background-color:white;border:none;">                 
                            <div data-qid="169" data-aid="0" data-name="question" style="cursor: pointer;">
                                <div style="margin-bottom:-7px;">
                                    <h5 style="font-family: &quot;Verdana&quot;, Verdana;font-weight: bolder;margin-top:0px;"><span style="white-space:pre-wrap;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam?</span>
                                </div>                   
                            </div> 
                        </div> 
                        <br>
                    </div>
                    <!-- questions here -->
                    <div data-name="results">
                        <!-- individual question container with DETAILS link  -->
                        <div class="card-header" id="header170" style="border-radius:10px;background-color:white;border:none;">                 
                            <div data-qid="170" data-aid="0" data-name="question" style="cursor: pointer;">
                                <div style="margin-bottom:-7px;">
                                    <h5 style="font-family: &quot;Verdana&quot;, Verdana;font-weight: bolder;margin-top:0px;"><span style="white-space:pre-wrap;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam?</span>
                                </div>                   
                            </div> 
                        </div> 
                        <br>
                    </div>    
                    <!-- questions here -->
                    <div data-name="results">
                        <!-- individual question container with DETAILS link  -->
                        <div class="card-header" id="header171" style="border-radius:10px;background-color:white;border:none;">                 
                            <div data-qid="171" data-aid="0" data-name="question" style="cursor: pointer;">
                                <div style="margin-bottom:-7px;">
                                    <h5 style="font-family: &quot;Verdana&quot;, Verdana;font-weight: bolder;margin-top:0px;"><span style="white-space:pre-wrap;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam?</span>
                                </div>                   
                            </div> 
                        </div> 
                        <br>
                    </div>     
                    <!-- questions here -->
                    <div data-name="results">
                        <!-- individual question container with DETAILS link  -->
                        <div class="card-header" id="header172" style="border-radius:10px;background-color:white;border:none;">                 
                            <div data-qid="172" data-aid="0" data-name="question" style="cursor: pointer;">
                                <div style="margin-bottom:-7px;">
                                    <h5 style="font-family: &quot;Verdana&quot;, Verdana;font-weight: bolder;margin-top:0px;"><span style="white-space:pre-wrap;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam?</span>
                                </div>                   
                            </div> 
                        </div> 
                        <br>
                    </div>      
                    <!-- END OF LIST OF QUESTIONS -->
                </div> 
            </div>
    </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do it by making the list show and hide (instead of removing it) and then making the single answer view fixed to the top of the viewport (instead of getting added at the top of the page). That way, scrolling position is naturally preserved without having to manage some sort of state.

If you want to animate hiding the questions, you should use CSS for that.

```js
//********************************************************************************************************
//     Clone Question, display on its own, hide existing list of questions
//********************************************************************************************************     
$(document).on('click', '[data-name="question"]', function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    var qid = $(this).attr("data-qid");//id of the question being answered        
    //var clone = $(this).clone();//clone entire question element to paste into new space
    var clone = $('#header'+qid).clone();//clone entire question element to paste into new space    
    $('#load_data').removeClass('fadein').addClass('fadeout')
    $(clone).hide().appendTo('#load_single_answer').fadeIn(1000);
    var html = '<div class="container">'+//provide an X button to close the single question display
        '<div class="exit btn btn-light btn-space col-12 box displ text-center align-self-center" style="font-size:120%"><strong>X</strong></div>'+
        '</div>';                    
    $(html).appendTo('#load_single_answer'); 
});
//**********************************************************************
//    Close single question display, bring back the list of questions
//**********************************************************************
$(document).on('click', '.exit', function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    //restore all background data
    $('#load_data').removeClass('fadeout').addClass('fadein')
    $('#load_single_answer').empty();//clear out single answer data
});
```

```css
#load_single_answer {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 1;
}
.fadeout {
 opacity: 0;
 transition-duration: .5s;
}
.fadein {
 opacity: 1;
 transition-duration: .5s;
}
```

```html
<head>
     <!-- JQuery -->
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>   
     <!-- Bootstrap -->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
     <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body style="background-color:#f2f2f2;">

    <!-- loading point for displaying single questions and answers -->
    <div class='container' style="max-width:900px;">
        <div id="load_single_answer"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="main">
            <!-- Question and Answers loaded here via ajax call -->
            <div id = "dataX" class="container p-0" style="max-width: 900px;">
                <div id="load_data">               
                    <!-- BEGINNING LIST OF QUESTIONS-->
                    <!-- questions here -->
                    <div data-name="results">
                        <!-- individual question container with DETAILS link  -->
                        <div class="card-header" id="header165" style="border-radius:10px;background-color:white;border:none;">                 
                            <div data-qid="165" data-aid="0" data-name="question" style="cursor: pointer;">
                                <div style="margin-bottom:-7px;">
                                    <h5 style="font-family: &quot;Verdana&quot;, Verdana;font-weight: bolder;margin-top:0px;"><span style="white-space:pre-wrap;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam?</span>
                                </div>                   
                            </div> 
                        </div> 
                        <br>
                    </div>                    
                    <!-- questions here -->
                    <div data-name="results">
                        <!-- individual question container with DETAILS link  -->
                        <div class="card-header" id="header166" style="border-radius:10px;background-color:white;border:none;">                 
                            <div data-qid="166" data-aid="0" data-name="question" style="cursor: pointer;">
                                <div style="margin-bottom:-7px;">
                                    <h5 style="font-family: &quot;Verdana&quot;, Verdana;font-weight: bolder;margin-top:0px;"><span style="white-space:pre-wrap;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam?</span>
                                </div>                   
                            </div> 
                        </div> 
                        <br>
                    </div>
                    <!-- questions here -->
                    <div data-name="results">
                        <!-- individual question container with DETAILS link  -->
                        <div class="card-header" id="header167" style="border-radius:10px;background-color:white;border:none;">                 
                            <div data-qid="167" data-aid="0" data-name="question" style="cursor: pointer;">
                                <div style="margin-bottom:-7px;">
                                    <h5 style="font-family: &quot;Verdana&quot;, Verdana;font-weight: bolder;margin-top:0px;"><span style="white-space:pre-wrap;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam?</span>
                                </div>                   
                            </div> 
                        </div> 
                        <br>
                    </div>
                    <!-- questions here -->
                    <div data-name="results">
                        <!-- individual question container with DETAILS link  -->
                        <div class="card-header" id="header168" style="border-radius:10px;background-color:white;border:none;">                 
                            <div data-qid="168" data-aid="0" data-name="question" style="cursor: pointer;">
                                <div style="margin-bottom:-7px;">
                                    <h5 style="font-family: &quot;Verdana&quot;, Verdana;font-weight: bolder;margin-top:0px;"><span style="white-space:pre-wrap;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam?</span>
                                </div>                   
                            </div> 
                        </div> 
                        <br>
                    </div>
                    <!-- questions here -->
                    <div data-name="results">
                        <!-- individual question container with DETAILS link  -->
                        <div class="card-header" id="header169" style="border-radius:10px;background-color:white;border:none;">                 
                            <div data-qid="169" data-aid="0" data-name="question" style="cursor: pointer;">
                                <div style="margin-bottom:-7px;">
                                    <h5 style="font-family: &quot;Verdana&quot;, Verdana;font-weight: bolder;margin-top:0px;"><span style="white-space:pre-wrap;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam?</span>
                                </div>                   
                            </div> 
                        </div> 
                        <br>
                    </div>
                    <!-- questions here -->
                    <div data-name="results">
                        <!-- individual question container with DETAILS link  -->
                        <div class="card-header" id="header170" style="border-radius:10px;background-color:white;border:none;">                 
                            <div data-qid="170" data-aid="0" data-name="question" style="cursor: pointer;">
                                <div style="margin-bottom:-7px;">
                                    <h5 style="font-family: &quot;Verdana&quot;, Verdana;font-weight: bolder;margin-top:0px;"><span style="white-space:pre-wrap;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam?</span>
                                </div>                   
                            </div> 
                        </div> 
                        <br>
                    </div>    
                    <!-- questions here -->
                    <div data-name="results">
                        <!-- individual question container with DETAILS link  -->
                        <div class="card-header" id="header171" style="border-radius:10px;background-color:white;border:none;">                 
                            <div data-qid="171" data-aid="0" data-name="question" style="cursor: pointer;">
                                <div style="margin-bottom:-7px;">
                                    <h5 style="font-family: &quot;Verdana&quot;, Verdana;font-weight: bolder;margin-top:0px;"><span style="white-space:pre-wrap;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam?</span>
                                </div>                   
                            </div> 
                        </div> 
                        <br>
                    </div>     
                    <!-- questions here -->
                    <div data-name="results">
                        <!-- individual question container with DETAILS link  -->
                        <div class="card-header" id="header172" style="border-radius:10px;background-color:white;border:none;">                 
                            <div data-qid="172" data-aid="0" data-name="question" style="cursor: pointer;">
                                <div style="margin-bottom:-7px;">
                                    <h5 style="font-family: &quot;Verdana&quot;, Verdana;font-weight: bolder;margin-top:0px;"><span style="white-space:pre-wrap;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam?</span>
                                </div>                   
                            </div> 
                        </div> 
                        <br>
                    </div>      
                    <!-- END OF LIST OF QUESTIONS -->
                </div> 
            </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  Your approach makes good sense.  Although, I seem to recall it is doable with hide/show - fadeIn/fadeOut, but cannot seem to find again, the example that showed how to make it work, without affecting the scroll position.  Thank you!

Comment: jquery `hide()` is implemented by setting `display: none;` on the object's CSS, so they won't take up any space anymore. By setting a CSS animation duration you can replicate fade in a more performant way!

Comment: You could do it using `hide()` and `show()` if you stored the scrolling position in a JS variable and then force scrolled the page to that position once the box is closed, but that will open you up to potential browser inconsistency and implementation bugs, as well as being a less performant method.

Comment: I added a .5s fade in and out to the answer

Comment: I noticed that with your solution, the Bootstrap "container" class, limited at 900px in my example, no longer works.  It was meant to keep the single question centered and limited in width to 900px.  Your example now widens the text to the extreme left/right of the screen (expand the snippet to full screen).  Seems like "position:fixed" destroys the "container" functionality.  I took the CSS "left: 0" out , also tried "margin: auto" which did not help.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: The default `position: relative;` setting positions the div relative to the parent (think "inside" it) but when you set that to `position: fixed;` it's positioned relative to the window, so you need to reconstruct the `max-width: 900px` set by the bootstrap container class. The simplest way to do it (if you don't want to just set it yourself) would be to put a bootstrap container inside of the fixed div, and then build your answer normally inside of that.

Comment: Also, my real example has much more other text (answers) for each question, which can make it longer.  Using the fixed approach does not allow the single display to have a scrollbar, but fixed at the top,  and the scrollbar is for the hidden listing in the background... more work to be done here for me!

Comment: You can add a scrollable div inside the fixed element which will let the user scroll to see all the content. `overflow: scroll;`

Comment: I'm happy to help with questions but if you need work done, I'm a freelancer!

Comment: I just posted my solution using your suggestion of using the scroll position instead. Works great!   Thanks for the back and forth.  Yes, I may need some help in the future...but just hacking around for now!

Answer (score 0):

I chose to use the scroll method - When the question to display is clicked, store the scroll position, hide the list, show the single question.  When the "X" is clicked to close the single question, show the list, empty the single question holder, then restore the scroll position.

Works like a charm, and doesn't experience the issues I wrote about above with Bootstrap's container formatting, and scroll issues (if it's a long question/answer), etc.

Code below:

```js
    //********************************************************************************************************
    //     Clone Question, display on its own, hide existing list of questions
    //********************************************************************************************************     
    $(document).on('click', '[data-name="question"]', function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        position = $(window).scrollTop();//preserve position of list
        //alert(position);
        var qid = $(this).attr("data-qid");//id of the question being answered        
        //var clone = $(this).clone();//clone entire question element to paste into new space
        var clone = $('#header'+qid).clone();//clone entire question element to paste into new space    
        $('#load_data').hide();
        $(clone).hide().appendTo('#load_single_answer').fadeIn(1000);
        var html = '<div class="container">'+//provide an X button to close the single question display
            '<div class="exit btn btn-light btn-space col-12 box displ text-center align-self-center" style="font-size:120%"><strong>X</strong></div>'+
            '</div>';                    
        $(html).appendTo('#load_single_answer'); 
    });
    //**********************************************************************
    //    Close single question display, bring back the list of questions
    //**********************************************************************
    $(document).on('click', '.exit', function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        //restore all background data
        $('#load_data').fadeIn(500); 
        $('#load_single_answer').empty();//clear out single answer data
        $(window).scrollTop(position); 
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- JQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>   
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body style="background-color:#f2f2f2;">

    <!-- loading point for displaying single questions and answers -->
    <div class='container' style="max-width:900px;">
        <div id="load_single_answer"></div>
    </div>
 
    <div id="main">
            <!-- Question and Answers loaded here via ajax call -->
            <div id = "dataX" class="container p-0" style="max-width: 900px;">
                <div id="load_data">               
                    <!-- BEGINNING LIST OF QUESTIONS-->
                    <!-- questions here -->
                    <div data-name="results">
                        <!-- individual question container with DETAILS link  -->
                        <div class="card-header" id="header165" style="border-radius:10px;background-color:white;border:none;">                 
                            <div data-qid="165" data-aid="0" data-name="question" style="cursor: pointer;">
                                <div style="margin-bottom:-7px;">
                                    <h5 style="font-family: &quot;Verdana&quot;, Verdana;font-weight: bolder;margin-top:0px;"><span style="white-space:pre-wrap;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam?</span>
                                </div>                   
                            </div> 
                        </div> 
                        <br>
                    </div>                    
                    <!-- questions here -->
                    <div data-name="results">
                        <!-- individual question container with DETAILS link  -->
                        <div class="card-header" id="header166" style="border-radius:10px;background-color:white;border:none;">                 
                            <div data-qid="166" data-aid="0" data-name="question" style="cursor: pointer;">
                                <div style="margin-bottom:-7px;">
                                    <h5 style="font-family: &quot;Verdana&quot;, Verdana;font-weight: bolder;margin-top:0px;"><span style="white-space:pre-wrap;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam?</span>
                                </div>                   
                            </div> 
                        </div> 
                        <br>
                    </div>
                    <!-- questions here -->
                    <div data-name="results">
                        <!-- individual question container with DETAILS link  -->
                        <div class="card-header" id="header167" style="border-radius:10px;background-color:white;border:none;">                 
                            <div data-qid="167" data-aid="0" data-name="question" style="cursor: pointer;">
                                <div style="margin-bottom:-7px;">
                                    <h5 style="font-family: &quot;Verdana&quot;, Verdana;font-weight: bolder;margin-top:0px;"><span style="white-space:pre-wrap;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam?</span>
                                </div>                   
                            </div> 
                        </div> 
                        <br>
                    </div>
                    <!-- questions here -->
                    <div data-name="results">
                        <!-- individual question container with DETAILS link  -->
                        <div class="card-header" id="header168" style="border-radius:10px;background-color:white;border:none;">                 
                            <div data-qid="168" data-aid="0" data-name="question" style="cursor: pointer;">
                                <div style="margin-bottom:-7px;">
                                    <h5 style="font-family: &quot;Verdana&quot;, Verdana;font-weight: bolder;margin-top:0px;"><span style="white-space:pre-wrap;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam?</span>
                                </div>                   
                            </div> 
                        </div> 
                        <br>
                    </div>
                    <!-- questions here -->
                    <div data-name="results">
                        <!-- individual question container with DETAILS link  -->
                        <div class="card-header" id="header169" style="border-radius:10px;background-color:white;border:none;">                 
                            <div data-qid="169" data-aid="0" data-name="question" style="cursor: pointer;">
                                <div style="margin-bottom:-7px;">
                                    <h5 style="font-family: &quot;Verdana&quot;, Verdana;font-weight: bolder;margin-top:0px;"><span style="white-space:pre-wrap;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam?</span>
                                </div>                   
                            </div> 
                        </div> 
                        <br>
                    </div>
                    <!-- questions here -->
                    <div data-name="results">
                        <!-- individual question container with DETAILS link  -->
                        <div class="card-header" id="header170" style="border-radius:10px;background-color:white;border:none;">                 
                            <div data-qid="170" data-aid="0" data-name="question" style="cursor: pointer;">
                                <div style="margin-bottom:-7px;">
                                    <h5 style="font-family: &quot;Verdana&quot;, Verdana;font-weight: bolder;margin-top:0px;"><span style="white-space:pre-wrap;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam?</span>
                                </div>                   
                            </div> 
                        </div> 
                        <br>
                    </div>    
                    <!-- questions here -->
                    <div data-name="results">
                        <!-- individual question container with DETAILS link  -->
                        <div class="card-header" id="header171" style="border-radius:10px;background-color:white;border:none;">                 
                            <div data-qid="171" data-aid="0" data-name="question" style="cursor: pointer;">
                                <div style="margin-bottom:-7px;">
                                    <h5 style="font-family: &quot;Verdana&quot;, Verdana;font-weight: bolder;margin-top:0px;"><span style="white-space:pre-wrap;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam?</span>
                                </div>                   
                            </div> 
                        </div> 
                        <br>
                    </div>     
                    <!-- questions here -->
                    <div data-name="results">
                        <!-- individual question container with DETAILS link  -->
                        <div class="card-header" id="header172" style="border-radius:10px;background-color:white;border:none;">                 
                            <div data-qid="172" data-aid="0" data-name="question" style="cursor: pointer;">
                                <div style="margin-bottom:-7px;">
                                    <h5 style="font-family: &quot;Verdana&quot;, Verdana;font-weight: bolder;margin-top:0px;"><span style="white-space:pre-wrap;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam?</span>
                                </div>                   
                            </div> 
                        </div> 
                        <br>
                    </div>      
                    <!-- END OF LIST OF QUESTIONS -->
                </div> 
            </div>
    </div>
    </body>
```